# Reload UIViews of nearby cells in a carousel using UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, carousel

I have a carousel made using CollectionView. You can expand and collapse a cell thus I am adding and removing subviews depending on that action. However, I can only change the UI of the current cell thus when you move to the next cell, the UI is broken. How can I also change the UI of the neighboring cells based on the actions I have made on the current cell?

Comment: It would be helpful to have code snippet and UI screenshots

Comment: Thing is cell gets Dequeued again when you scroll to next cell , to make it collapsable or expandable state you Explicitly need to manage a Value on base of which cells will be Dequeued that value is to be responsible that cell at index is to be Expanded or collapsed just like maintaining a Array of bools with count equal to number of source array , true if to be Expand, false to keep cell in Collapsed condition

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue, you are looking for something to reload the cells surrounding the cell you are currently interacting with.

There is a very easy and brutal way:

```
yourCollectionView.reloadData()
```

But I feel like you are looking for something better. What you could do is simply grab the index path of your cell, calculate the index path of the next and previous cell and use something like that:

```
yourCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [previousIndexPAth,nextIndexPath])
```

If you absolutely just want to update the layout of your cells, you can do something like so:

```
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: yourPreviousIndexPath) {
    cell.layoutSubviews()
}
```

Comment: Hmm I don't need to reload the data itself, I just need to reload the views

Comment: calling enter of these functions will also trigger `layoutSubview` function. So this will reload your views as well